# Cypress + Cucumber - Reuse Steps with dynamic values

Tags: typescript, cucumber, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have feature file like where field name and message are dynamic and values are fetched from examples:

```
Scenario: Validation of various fields 
        Given When User is on the Details Page
        When User enters the incorrect value "<accountname>" in the form
        Then Validation error "<message>" should appear
    Examples:
        | accountname | message |
        | zb  | Fiels name can not be less than 3 char. |    
        | 'ac@' | ''ac@'' is not a valid input. |
```

Steps definition for the 'when statement' is written as follows:

```
When (
  "User enters the incorrect value {string} in the form", (accountname) => {  
      page.enterAccountName(accountname);
    }
);
```

page file is:

```
enterAccountName(accountname: any) {
      cy.xpath(selectors.inputAccountName).type(`${accountname}`);
  }
```

inputAccountName is an xpath coming from locator file selectors.ts

```
export default {
  inputAccountName: '//input[@class="account"]',
  inputDataBaseName: '//input[@class="databse"]',
  inputEmail: '//input[@type="email"]',
  inputPassword: '//input[@type="password"]',
  };
```

The above code is to validate one of the fields in a form, I want to reuse the above code(when statement) to validate 5 other fields(the selector will be different). I need to update the when statement something like follows:

```
When User enters the incorrect value "<accountname>" in "<fieldname>" in the form
```

where my 'fieldname' values should be coming from the selectors.ts file and locator each time will change but steps will remain the same

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
When ("User enters the incorrect value {string} for the field {string} in the form", 
(accountname:string, fieldClass:'account'|'database'|'email'|'password') => {  
       cy.xpath(`//input[@class="${fieldClass}"]`).type(`${accountname}`);
    }
);
```